# Unzip only certain files who's name contain a number that matches a list of numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, zip, extract

I have ~5530 zip files in a directory that are all named in a certain style. E.g.:

> monatswerte_RR_02076_19370101_19701230_hist.zip

Now i want to extract only the files which match in the 5 digit pattern after the "RR_" any entry in a ~250 lines long list (ids.txt) of 5 digit numbers.
I have tried to solve the problem with a bash script but that does not work:

```
for i in "ls"; do if [[$i ==*"cat ids.txt"*]]; then "unzip $i" fi; done
```

Some rows of the ids.txt:

> ~ » cat Dokumente/Schneehydro/historical/ids.txt
>   00013 
>   00050
>   00085
>   00107
>   00108
>   ...
>   05691
>   05804
>   05874
>   15574

Comment: I using a programming language like `Python` or `PHP` an option?

Comment: Can you clarify the constraints on the 5-digit id -- is it any 5-digit number, or you have a list of specific ids?

Comment: Add an excerpt from file ids.txt to your question.

Comment: Well i know a little bit of Python, but i thought doing it in bash is faster.
For the constraints, it is a list of specific id's. I will try to add an excerpt to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`bash`** + **`grep`** solution:

```
for f in *_RR_[0-9]*.zip; do 
    num="${f#*_RR_}"
    num=${num:0:5}
    grep -qx "$num" ids.txt && unzip -q "$f"
done
```